# how to adjust dynamic buttons added in wpf?

Tags: wpf

I added 8 buttons dynamically based on requirements.

All buttons in Stack Panel.

```
int Total_images = img.Count;
int Page_size = 6;
int capacity = 0;
if (Total_images % Page_size == 0){
    capacity = Total_images / Page_size;
}
else{
    capacity = (Total_images / Page_size) + 1;
}
int j = 1;
if (sp.Children.Capacity==0){
    //if (capacity <= 4){
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i){
            Button button = new Button(){
                Content = string.Format("" + j),
                Tag = i
            };
            j += 1;
            button.Width = 20;
            button.Height = 20;
            button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
            sp.Children.Add(button);
        }
}
```

- It displays 8 buttons like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8.
- I have two buttons next and previous.
- first, I have to display 4 buttons like 1 2 3 4,
- then display remaining 4 buttons.
- if I click next button, it should display next 4 buttons,
- if I click previous, it should display previous 4 buttons.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: help me please.

Comment: ideally you should do this with collection binding with a view model

Comment: i'm new to wpf. please explain briefly

Comment: @ARYA I just saw `<Image Source="{Binding Path=UriSource}"/>` in your last, now deleted question. Note that this is nonsense. It ceates a new BitmapFrame by automatic type conversion from Uri to ImageSource, although there is already a BitmapImage. Replace it by `<Image Source="{Binding}"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear your StackPanel and add the new buttons:

```
NextButton_Click(sender...)
{
   sp.Children.Clear();

   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
        Button button = new Button(){
            Content = (i+5).ToString();
        };
        button.Width = 20;
        button.Height = 20;
        button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
        sp.Children.Add(button); 
   }
}

PreviousButton_Click(sender...)
{
   sp.Children.Clear();

   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
        Button button = new Button(){
            Content = (i+1).ToString();
        };
        button.Width = 20;
        button.Height = 20;
        button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
        sp.Children.Add(button); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Generating What is expected, but Tag value for first 3 buttons and next 3 buttons same.

Comment: This was just to give you an idea of how you can remove and add items to the StackPanel from code.

Answer (score 1):

ideally you should do this with collection binding with a view model 
this would look something like this, **note this is only a basic example to point you in the right direction**

```
class ViewModelPager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 20));
    public IEnumerable<int> ShowItems => Items.Skip(Page * 4).Take(4);
    private int page;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Page
    {
        get { return page; }
        set
        {
            page = value;
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Page)));
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ShowItems)));
        }
    }

    public ICommand Next { get; set; }
    public ICommand Previous { get; set; }
}
```

then in your XAML you would have no code behind

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModelPager/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ShowItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Slider Value="{Binding Page}"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding Next}">Next</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding Previous}">Previous</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

for how to implement the commands see [RelayCommand](https://gist.github.com/schuster-rainer/2648922)